# Pairing numbers (a,b) in an array such a way that a*2 >=b

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, java-8

I am trying to solve pairing numbers (a,b) in an array such a way that `a*2 >=b`. Where a and b are numbers from input array.

Examples:

input: `a[]  = {1,2,3,4,5}`

output: 2

explanation:

- we can pair 1 with 3
- 2 with 4 or 5

input: `a[]  = {4,3,2,1,5}`

output: 2

explanation:

- we can pair 1 with 3
- 2 with 4 or 5

input: `a[]  = {4,3,2,1,5,6}`

output: 3

explanation:

- we can pair 5 with 1
- 2 with 4
- 3 with 6

I tried to solve the problem using recursion like below, but this does not give any right results. Any help would be appreciated.

- Sort the input array
- **if** a[start] * 2 >= [end] found then `add 1` to result recur for  `start +1` and `end - 1`
- **else** recur for `(start + 1, end)`, `(start, end - 1)` and
  `(start + 1, end - 1)`

Idea is matching `a[start]` with **remaining** elements in the array and get max result.

```
    public static int countPairs(int[] a){
       Arrays.sort(a);
       return countPairs(a,a.length,0,a.length-1);
    }

    public static int countPairs(int[] a, int n, int start, int end){


        if(end == start){
            return 0;
        }
        if(start >= n || end < 0){
            return 0;
        }

         System.out.print("matching start: "+start + " and end "+end+"   ");System.out.println("matching "+a[start] + " and "+a[end]);

        if(a[start] < a[end] && a[start] * 2 >= a[end]  ){

            int res = countPairs(a,n,start+1,end-1) +1;
             //System.out.print("inside if matching start: "+start + " and end "+end+"   ");System.out.println("matching "+a[start] + " and "+a[end] + " count is "+res);
            return res;
        }
        else{

            return max(countPairs(a,n,start+1,end) ,
                    countPairs(a,n,start,end - 1),countPairs(a,n,start+1,end - 1));
        }

    }
```

tests:

```
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;


public class CountingPairsTest {

    static int countPairs(int[] a){
        return PairingNumbers.countPairs(a);
    }

    @Test
     public void test1(){
        int[] a = {1,2,3,4,5};
        System.out.println("****************************************\n" + Arrays.toString(a));
        int count = countPairs(a);
        System.out.println("count "+count);
    }

    @Test public void test2(){
        int[] a = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
        System.out.println("****************************************\n" + Arrays.toString(a));
        int count = countPairs(a);
        System.out.println("count "+count);
    }

    @Test public void test5(){
        int[] a = {1,2,3,7,4,5,6};
        System.out.println("****************************************\n" + Arrays.toString(a));
        int count = countPairs(a);
        System.out.println("count "+count);
    }

    @Test public void test6(){
        int[] a = {9,8,20,15,21};

        System.out.println("****************************************\n" + Arrays.toString(a));
        int count = countPairs(a);
        System.out.println("count "+count);
    }

    @Test public  void test3(){
        int[] a = {5,4,3,2,1};
        System.out.println("****************************************\n" + Arrays.toString(a));
        int count = countPairs(a);
        System.out.println("count "+count);
    }

    @Test public void test4(){
        int[] a = {2,4,5,3,1};

        System.out.println("****************************************\n" + Arrays.toString(a));
        int count = countPairs(a);
        System.out.println("count "+count);
    }

    @Test public void test7(){
        int[] a = new Random().ints(10,1,100).toArray();// IntStream.range(1,100).toArray();


        System.out.println("****************************************\n" + Arrays.toString(a));
        int count = countPairs(a);
        System.out.println("count "+count);
    }
    @Test public void test8(){
        int[] a = new Random().ints(10,1,10).toArray();// IntStream.range(1,100).toArray();


        System.out.println("****************************************\n" + Arrays.toString(a));
        int count = countPairs(a);
        System.out.println("count "+count);
    }
}
```

Comment: where is your question?

Comment: Edited. The algorithm does not work correctly. could not able to figure out the exact issue..

Comment: Is the recursion some kind of a requirement? If I understand the problem correctly you can count all pair using 2 nested loops.

Comment: It might be worth adding some example expected results. What are the pairs for the `test1`?

Comment: Recursion is not necessary, but I tried to solve the problem in this manner. Let me add the examples

Comment: May the numbers be negative? (If the array is [-3, -4] there is no solution.)

Comment: @OleV.V. or can the array contain duplicates? or the pairs are unique, is: `1,2` same as `2, 1`?

Comment: @OleV.V. No negative numbers present as per requirement

Comment: @OleV.V. yes it can have duplicates.

Comment: I assume given number can appear in only one pair, it can't be reused?

Comment: @Amongalen yes, you are right. a number `x` can be paired only with another number `y`

Comment: `we can pair 1 with 3` => How? `1 * 2 < 3` and not `>= 3` or may be you mean `3 * 2 >= 1`?

Comment: @vivek_23, 2 * 3 >= 1.. yes...

Comment: As per OleV.V.'s answer, this is trivial. Are you sure you included all the requirements?

Comment: What does this mean "2 * 3 >= 1.. yes..." in the comment by secret super star just above? What are `a` and `b` in this explanation?

Comment: @גלעדברקן `a` and `b` refer to values from array

Comment: @Dukeling, this was the question.. I remember for the input `[1,2,3,4,5]` the expected output was `2` ..

Comment: secret super star, if 2 and 3 are `a` and `b` then what is 1? I see only two parameters being compared in the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest that the answer is `a.length / 2`. Half of the length of the array (rounded down if the length was odd). You can pair the numbers any way you like. For non-negative *a* and *b* if *a* * 2 < *b*, just swap *a* and *b* and you will have *a* * 2 >= *b*. So since it takes two numbers to make a pair, you can always form precisely as many pairs as half of the length of the array.

Example (from the comments): [1, 2, 2, 2]. Length is 4, half of the length is 2, so there should be 2 pairs. Let’s check: (1, 2) is a nice pair because 1 * 2 >= 2. (2, 2) is another nice pair since 2 * 2 >= 2. In this case we didn’t even need any swapping (on the other hand the same pairs would have worked *with* swapping too: 2 * 2 >= 1 and 2 * 2 >= 2).

It will not always work if the array may contain negative numbers. So you may want to add a validation of the array that checks that it doesn’t.

**What went wrong in your solution?**

Your recursive algorithm is wrong. Say the array is [2, 3, 7, 9]. Clearly (2, 3) and (7, 9) are nice pairs, so there are two pairs here. The way you describe your algorithm, since (2, 9) is not a valid pair, you discard at least one of 2 and 9, leaving no chance of forming two pairs from the remaining numbers.

Comment: you suggest that the result is `array.length / 2`?

Comment: @Eugene yes precisely since if `a` < `b` and `a * 2 < b` , then , we make `a` as `b` and `b` as `a`. So, we will always get length / 2 pairs.

Comment: @vivek_23 how about `[1,2,2,2]`?

Comment: @OleV.V. oh! I thought that `[1,2]`, `[1,2]` (second two) and `[1,2]` (third two) would work also

Comment: @Eugene As I understood reuse of the 1 is not allowed. Amongalan asked: *I assume given number can appear in only one pair, it can't be reused?* secret super star replied: *yes, you are right…* (but my quotes are selective, so I could have been wrong).

Comment: @Eugene, for input `[1,2,2,2]`   `1` and `2` can be grouped (multiply 1 with 2) and `2` & `2` (multiply anyone) grouped. But unfortunately, If I am not able to recollect, if the ask we there that `a` should be appearing before `b` in the input array. which means that I need choose `b` from `i + 1` where `a` is present at `i`th index.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it this way:

i. sort array.

ii. for each number **a** find the left most position **p** of array which contains >= 2*b. then you can count how many number satisfied.

Complexity: **O(nlogn)+nlogn**

Comment: second stage is linear (indexes move only to the right)  (does not important for overall runtime)

Comment: From the given examples I assume that given number `a` can appear in only one pair. I think that for input {1,2,4} there is only one pair being **one** of those: (1,2), (1,4), (2,4) - not all of them.